# PHP - How to detect if 'ok' button on downloading the file was clicked?

Tags: php, download

Is there a way in PHP or javascript to know whether the user clicked the 'ok' button once a download box popup?

[image]

I wanted to count how many download have made to that specific file,
I wanted to done it this way by detecting if 'ok' was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is possible, even with javascript. Because, that download dialog is beyond the scope of javascript. There are no solution to your problem.

You can only add counter +1 to your download counter without knowing that the user are actually clicking 'OK'.

Answer (score 0):

The force download method in Google Chrome is different. This will download the file automatically if you click on the link. No messages like this will be displayed. So if you are finding some method for the above problem, this will not be a cross browser compatible solution.